# Cómo ajustar esta consulta SPARQL con fecha?

Tags: python

Dado un RDFGraph con la siguiente informacion:

```
ex:Mustang ex:Deportivo dbr:Ford ;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina ;
    ex:potencia "450";
    ex:km "120000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2020-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ford Mustang GT"@en .

ex:GT ex:Deportivo dbr:Ford ;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina ;
    ex:potencia "550";
    ex:km "25000";
    schema:dateManufactured "1968-04-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ford GT"@en .

ex:Fiesta ex:Utilitario dbr:Ford ;
    schema:Motor ex:Diesel ;
    ex:potencia "100";
    ex:km "45000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2020-02-10"^^xsd:date ;
    rdfs:label "Ford Fiesta"@en .

ex:206 ex:Utilitario dbr:Peugeot ;
    schema:Motor ex:Diesel ;
    ex:potencia "68";
    ex:km "173100";
    schema:dateManufactured "2004-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
    rdfs:label "Peugeot 206"@en .

ex:DMC-12 ex:Deportivo dbr:Delorean_Motor_Company;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina ;
    ex:potencia "130";
    ex:km "110000";
    schema:dateManufactured "1981-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    rdfs:label "Delorean DMC-12"@en .

ex:Firebird ex:Deportivo dbr:Pontiac;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina;
    ex:potencia "165";
    ex:km "100000";
    schema:dateManufactured "1975-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    rdfs:label "Pontiac Firebird Trans-Am V8"@en .

ex:California ex:Deportivo dbr:Ferrari;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina;
    ex:potencia "460";
    ex:km "500000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2010-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ferrari California"@en .

ex:Enzo ex:Deportivo dbr:Ferrari;
    schema:Motor ex:Gasolina;
    ex:potencia "";
    ex:km "200000";
    schema:dateManufactured "2002-05-29"^^xsd:date ;
    schema:wasInCompetition dbr:LeMans;
    rdfs:label "Ferrari Enzo"@en .

'''
```

Necesito: **Seleccionar todas las entidades y su motorización (por schema:Motor) con fecha de fabricación posterior al año 2000**

He conseguido lo siguiente:

```
q ='''
    SELECT ?h ?r ?t
     WHERE {
        ?r schema:Motor ?t .
        ?r schema:dateManufactured ?v .
     }
'''
```

Y esto me devuelve los resultados, ¿pero como puedo añadirle el filtro de la fecha?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Esta es la forma de filtrar por año, al menos, que me ha funcionado:

```
q ='''
    SELECT ?h ?r ?t
     WHERE {
        ?r schema:Motor ?t .
        ?r schema:dateManufactured ?v
        FILTER (year(?v) < 2000)
     }
'''
```